# Is putting variables from .env/.ini/ in Enum good?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, constants, pep

According to [PEP 435](https://peps.python.org/pep-0435/) `Enum` class is

```
An enumeration is a set of symbolic names bound to unique, constant values. 
Within an enumeration, the values can be compared by identity, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.
```

Should we store variables from `.env`, `.ini` or environmental variables in such a class, or is it overkill?

```
from enum import Enum
from decouple import config


class Constants(Enum):
    username = config('DATABASE_USERNAME')
    password = config('DATABASE_PASSWORD')
    host = config('DATABASE_HOST')
    port = config('DATABASE_HOST', cast=int)
```

Is the above a good idea in the ,,art of code''? Or maybe the better approach is to call each time `config` function whenever we need that variable in code?

Comment: As the description says, they're usually *constant* values, not values that are computed.

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration values do not change during the run of the program -- in other words, they are constant while the program is running -- and you want to be able to access them is

`do_a_thing(Constants.host.value, Constants.port.value)`

then sure, there's nothing wrong with doing it that way.